# How to prevent SliverAppBar from scrolling when touch is focused on another widget

Tags: google-maps, dart, flutter, uiscrollview

I have a SliverAppBar that I want to be hidden when the user scrolls down on the page. The problem is that I have a Google Map widget that is causing the app bar to move as well, when I only want it to move only when my touch is off the Google Map. Is there a way to [prevent this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2grqr.jpg)?

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return SafeArea(
    child: Scaffold(
  body: CustomScrollView(
    slivers: <Widget>[
      SliverAppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 5.0,
        pinned: false,
        snap: false,
        floating: false,
        expandedHeight: 200,
        flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
          background: Image.asset(
            'assets/events/city.jpeg',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      SliverFillRemaining(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: Container(
                  height: 200,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: GoogleMap(
                    initialCameraPosition:
                        CameraPosition(target: LatLng(50.0, 50.0)),
                    onMapCreated: (controller) {
                      setState(() {
                        _googleMapController = controller;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that adding a gestureRecognizer property to GoogleMap and passing in a Factory of type VerticalDragRecognizer allowed it to prevent the SliverAppBar from scrolling. It also works on any kind of scrolling you want for your app. See [this](https://youtu.be/X3Wr7pSORSc) for more info about it around the 50 minute mark.

```
SliverFillRemaining(
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Container(
              height: 200,
              width: double.infinity,
              child: GoogleMap(
                gestureRecognizers: Set()..add(Factory<VerticalDragGestureRecognizer>(
                    () => VerticalDragGestureRecognizer()
                )),
                scrollGesturesEngabled: true,
                initialCameraPosition:
                    CameraPosition(target: LatLng(50.0, 50.0)),
                onMapCreated: (controller) {
                  setState(() {
                    _googleMapController = controller;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  )
```